# Can one execute lldb debugger commands from inside the code being executed?

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

I would find it very convenient to execute an lldb. debugger command from inside the executing code.

( **Sort of moot - See comment on security issues below.**  It would only be proper if a very limited subset of safe operations was permitted.  Specifically I wanted to disable automatic breaking by lldb on a specific signal triggered and handled in a library )

The reason is we use CMake to generate An Xcode project file.
breakpoints which can be used in my case and can be edited to add "a debug action" to be executed at the breakpoint. The issue is the breakpoints are wiped with the project file is regenerated.  So I would like to be able to put it in the actual code :)

like

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
    if(inLLDBDebugger) {
        execute a debugger command
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Given that lldb can spawn arbitrary processes, this is a gigantic security hole. As an alternative, have you considered generating an lldb rcfile that contains a set of lldb commands?

Comment: I guess so - I have an alternative is when I generate the project with Cmake when it is done I explicitly write a shared breakpoint file into the Xcode project.  Xcode is pretty flexible but the fact the cMake generator is not too complete and buggy doesn't help :)  And regenerating the project  wastes the project customizations done in the ide.

Comment: @Botje: Why should we assume a security partition exists between the program being debugged and the debugger?  That’s like saying that a shell script shouldn’t be allowed to call `awk` because it can execute arbitrary code.

Comment: There are a couple stumbling blocks to doing this.  You can't load the LLDB.framework into your app and use it directly since most of the time when the debugger wants to inspect a process it suspends it first.  So you can't use LLDB in process to look at yourself.

Comment: Another slightly odd bit about debugging is that the debug agent becomes the parent of the task it's debugging (for POSIX reasons), so if you spawn an lldb tell it to attach to you, your child becomes your parent.  I haven't tried but that may not work well on all Unixes.

Comment: If the problem is mostly that you want to preserve Xcode customizations over CMake invocations, you can write a little wrapper around your CMake invocation that copies out the `<yourusername>.xcuserdatad` directory from the xcuserdata directory in the project, redoes the CMake, then puts it back in place.  That's where all your user customizations are stored.

Comment: @JimIngham. I actually resorted to something similar to keep the global main breakpoint to  to disable signal break in the project and then write them into the Xcode project when generated.  That is a good suggestion on saving and restoring the "user workspace" elements

Comment: Note that as of the latest Xcode releases you can now set process signal handling in your .lldbinit, you don't need to wait till the process is launched.  So at least that bit can be handled more simply.